# R Which repetition of loop produces a value larger than the critical value

Tags: r, function, loops

I have this function

```
   gillespieLO = function (N, n, ...) 
{
  tt = 0
  x = N$M
  S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
  u = nrow(S)
  v = ncol(S)
  tcrit = 2
  tvec = vector("numeric", n)
  xmat = matrix(ncol = u, nrow = n + 1)
  xmat[1, ] = x
  for (i in 1:n) {
    h = N$h(x, tt, ...)
    tt = tt + rexp(1, sum(h))
    j = sample(v, 1, prob = h)
    x = x + S[, j]
    tvec[i] = tt
    xmat[i + 1, ] = x
    poo = min(which(tvec>tcrit))
    if (i == poo){
      x[4] = x[4]+(10000/10)
    }
  }
  print(min(which(tvec>tcrit)))
  return(list(t = tvec, x = xmat))
}



LO = list()
LO$M = c(i = 1, ri = 0, I = 50, Lac = 20, ILac = 0, o = 1, Io = 0, RNAP = 100, RNAPo = 0, r = 0, z = 0)
LO$Pre = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), ncol=11, byrow=TRUE)
LO$Post = matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), ncol=11, byrow=TRUE)
LO$h = function(x,t,th=c(0.02,0.1,0.005,0.1,1,0.01,0.1,0.01,0.03,0.1,1e-05,0.01,0.002,0.01,0.001))
{
  with(as.list(c(x, th)), {
    return(c(th[1]*i, th[2]*ri, th[3]*I*Lac, th[4]*ILac, th[5]*I*o, th[6]*Io, th[7]*o*RNAP,
             th[8]*RNAPo, th[9]*RNAPo, th[10]*r, th[11]*Lac*z, th[12]*ri, th[13]*I, 
             th[13]*ILac, th[14]*r, th[15]*z))
  })
}
```

Putting

```
gillespieLO(LO,15)
```

gives

```
gillespieLO(LO,15)
[1] 11
$t
 [1] 0.001399092 0.053674441 0.132884069 0.156973856 0.365723847 0.700767071 1.178798507
 [8] 1.529528682 1.663988976 1.719413303 2.352115017 2.353169914 2.355999647 2.364615018
[15] 2.367255303

$x
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    1    0   50   20    0    1    0  100    0     0     0
 [2,]    1    0   49   20    0    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [3,]    1    0   48   19    1    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [4,]    1    0   47   18    2    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [5,]    1    0   46   17    3    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [6,]    1    0   47   18    2    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [7,]    1    0   46   17    3    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [8,]    1    0   45   16    4    0    1  100    0     0     0
 [9,]    1    0   44   15    5    0    1  100    0     0     0
[10,]    1    0   43   14    6    0    1  100    0     0     0
[11,]    1    0   42   13    7    0    1  100    0     0     0
[12,]    1    0   41   12    8    0    1  100    0     0     0
[13,]    1    0   40 1011    9    0    1  100    0     0     0
[14,]    1    0   39 1010   10    0    1  100    0     0     0
[15,]    1    0   38 1009   11    0    1  100    0     0     0
[16,]    1    0   37 1008   12    0    1  100    0     0     0
```

But I get errors,

```
1: In min(which(tvec > tcrit)) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
And I want to adapt it so that I can find the minimum value of `i` in my loop such that `tt>tcrit`
```

So I want to be doing something like min(which(i such that (tt > tcrit)) but I don't know how to write this in R.

Sorry for not being much help, because I've been trying to search for this, but I don't know how to explain it properly.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, perhaps with `dput(N)` and `dput(n)`? At present it's impossible to determine what's being input into the function.

Comment: Yeah sure. I've done some editing. So I'm going to edit it now, with my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `min` function returns `Inf` if no valid (non-NA) value is passed to it.

The value of `tcrit` is `2`. Values are assigned to `tvec` in loop at line `tvec[i] = tt`. Suppose in very 1st iteration the value assigned to `tvec[i]` is less than 1(which is less than `tcrit`). In that iteration the `which(tvec>tcrit)` will not return any valid value as no value is greater than `tcrit`. The `min` returns `Inf` as no valid value is passed to it.  You can try this case by a simple test:

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4)
> min(which(a>5))
[1] Inf
```

Hence to avoid the warning it would be better to check if there is `any` matching condition in `tvec` and then only apply for `min` otherwise `min` is invalid anyway.
Modified code :

```
if(any(which(tvec>tcrit))){
  poo = min(which(tvec>tcrit))
  if (i == poo){
    x[4] = x[4]+(10000/10)
  }
  print(min(which(tvec>tcrit)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting the same error message, and I can't see why. `In min(which(tvec > tcrit)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf` is the error message

Comment: @Gragbow I have modified my answer to by-pass `returning Inf` warning now. You wont get warning using the new code. Sorry. I should have explained you earlier itself but I had provided ways to take care of `Inf` value. The `Inf` related warning will not appear in current solution.

Comment: I know in theory that the `inf` warnings dont really matter. But it doesn't look very nice if each time I run my code. I didn't fully understand what you put before as I am quite new to R. However, thank you for explaining more, it's helped me a tonne

Comment: @gragbow If you take the latest code from my answer then even `Inf` warning won't appear. The `if` check ensures that at least 1 valid `tvec>tcrit` condition is met before passing it to `min`. This will avoid `Inf` warning. I will explain more with an example as part of my answer a little later.

Comment: @Gragbow I have added some more explanation about the reason for the error and solution to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop:

```
firstIalreadyFound <- FALSE
```

And then, make this line the first line within your loop:

```
if (tt > tcrit & !firstIalreadyFound){
    firstIalreadyFound <- TRUE
    # here, add the code you want to execute for this first i
}
```

It'll print i whenever the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: I think my code does work. But I am getting those warning messages. I only want the minimum value of `i` which satisfies this. And then I want to increased my 4th column value by 1000 for this ith repeat

Comment: Please, make sure you are precise about what question you would like to get answered. You didn't write that you want to do something in that very iteration. You just wrote you wanted to get the minimum i. ;)

Comment: To be honest the problem i had was how to get the minimum value of i for which tt > 20000. Because as soon as I got that I could adapt my code, like I have. But my code above comes up with error messages. What you initially said didn't give me the minimum, it just listed which `i` thank you for your help though. Oh sorry, I see what you mean, I didn't realise that was a big part. Yeah I needed that `i` in the iteration because I wanted to edit something for that specific `i`